Calculating Ricci tensor given the metric - undergraduate GR
I’ve been trying to solve the following problem:
Consider an $(N + n + 1)$-dimensional spacetime with coordinates $\{t, x^I, y^i\}$, where $I$ goes from 1 to $N$ and $i$ goes from 1 to $n$. Let the metric be
$
ds^2 = -dt^2 + a^2(t) \delta_{IJ} dx^I dx^J + b^2(t) \gamma_{ij}(y) dy^i dy^j
$
where $\delta_{IJ}$ is the usual Kronecker delta and $\gamma_{ij}(y)$ is the metric on an $n$-dimensional maximally symmetric spatial manifold. Imagine that we normalize the metric $\gamma$ such that the curvature parameter
$
k = \frac{R(\gamma)}{n(n-1)} 
$
is either $+1, 0,$ or $-1$, where $R(\gamma)$ is the Ricci scalar corresponding to the metric $\gamma_{ij}$.
(a) Calculate the Ricci tensor for this metric.
My attempt:
Knowing the metric we may calculate the Christoffel symbols. The non-zero components I’ve found are:
$\Gamma^t_{tt} = 0$,
$\Gamma^t_{IJ} = a\dot{a}\delta_{IJ}$,
$\Gamma^t_{ij} = b\dot{b}\gamma_{ij}$,
$\Gamma^I_{tJ} = \frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^I_{J}$,
$\Gamma^i_{tj} = \frac{\dot{b}}{b}\delta^i_{j}$,
$\Gamma^i_{jk} = \Gamma^i_{jk}(\gamma)$
By using the expression
$\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \partial_\mu g_{\nu \sigma} + \partial_\nu g_{\mu \sigma} - \partial_\sigma g_{\mu \nu} \right)$
However, I do not feel confident with these results and terms become very messy when trying to apply the symbols to calculate the Ricci tensor. This problem is from Sean Carroll’s book, “Spacetime and Geometry”, Chapter 8 (Exercise 1). I would appreciate any insight to verify my reasoning or perhaps tips regarding the nature of this metric, as I’ve never done a similar calculation.

It takes me 2 hours just to derive one term of the Schwarzchild metric for a class; it is pretty straight-forward, but takes very very long. I had even used all the tips and tricks. You must have patience.

I understand that, I’ve been through the same thing with other metrics. However, I just don’t know what to do in this question with this many indices in the line element and the gamma metric. I can’t figure out how to compute the derivatives required for the Ricci tensor. Is there some way I can check my work? It would help a lot as I’m self-studying.
